# Control Whitespace Around Chart Titles

Tags: charts, mschart

I'm using MS Chart to render charts to a PNG file.

There are two Chart Titles that collectively are taking an inordinate amount of space on the page because

- There is significant whitespace ("padding") around each title
- There is significant whitespace between the two titles

Reviewing the WinForms sample project at

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

I see that many aspects of the title (font, color, border, ...) can be changed but I do not see an option to control padding around an individual title, or extra whitespace between two titles.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could get adequate control over title rendering was to render it myself using a PostPaintHandler.

```
Chart c = new Chart();
c.PostPaint += (sender, e) => { /* Use e.ChartGraphics.Graphics for title */ };
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is the title eating all the space? You could check that by setting a title border to see exactly where its bounds are. Regardless, try setting the `InnerPlotPosition` for the corresponding `ChartArea` manually and see if you can solve the problem that way.

```
// Set the plotting area position. Coordinates of a plotting 
// area are relative to a chart area position.
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].InnerPlotPosition.Auto = false;
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].InnerPlotPosition.X = 10;
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].InnerPlotPosition.Y = 10;
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].InnerPlotPosition.Width = 80;
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].InnerPlotPosition.Height= 80;
```